# How to use Resource.RC file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

For context, I have been trying to include 2 PNG files with my C++ code, but I have not been able to figure out how to do so in Visual Studio 2019. I have searched through the docs and have not found anything helpful. How could I accomplish the three items listed below?

1. Correctly include files in a Resource.RC file (and correctly create a Resource.RC file)
2. Access these files in a filesystem-independent manner in C++ (no absolute paths)
3. Include these files when distributing an executable

My solution is laid out in the default manner: a References folder, External Dependencies folder, Header Files folder, Resource Files folder, and a Source Files folder.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here … but, once you have included an `.rc` file into your project, it is compiled and linked into the executable, so that any resources (images or others) can be accessed by that executable through calls to functions like `LoadResource` - there is no need for that app to search any file system.

Comment: What header would I need to include to get those methods?

Comment: Most of the required APIs are defined in the `Windows.h` header. Try creating a simple MFC application with the VS Wizard, and you'll see the basic layout of a project that includes resources. Often, the `.rc` file (there can be only one per project) will itself include one or more other `.rc2` files in which you can define your 'custom' resources.

Answer (score 1):

add .rc file refer to[microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-editors?view=vs-2019), you can use or load this rc resource refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadresource), windows api findresource and loadresource can use this rc file resource by define resouce id